How do I get rid of the quotation marks around title field in an entry of type @incollection?
Following the advice of the answer to the question Remove quotes from inbook reference title with biblatex, I added
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, InCollection]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, InCollection]{title}{#1}

to the preamble. All quotation marks around title fields have disappeared in the bibliography, except for the ones that occur in entries of type @incollection. How may this problem be avoided?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz If you look at the question I refer to, it has no such compilable code and it received 22 upvotes as well as a very good answer. No sizes fit all.

The reason you're being asked for code is that you're not asking for a generic way to do something, but describing unwanted behaviour of your code, without showing us the code.

A mwe would make it easier for future users with the same problem to check if they indeed have the same problem as you and it would also save users willing to help you from having to set up a test document and guessing what you might have in your code.

I've taken the liberty of providing some pretty-printing and of editing the title of your query in order to clarify its objective. Feel free to revert.

For the most part TeX programming is case sensitive, meaning that
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, InCollection]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, InCollection]{title}{#1}

and
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, incollection]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, incollection]{title}{#1}

do different things.
For the most part (again), biblatex uses lowercase only names in the data model, meaning that entry types and fields need to be given in all lowercase. Unfortunately(?), the .bib file syntax is not case sensitive when it comes to entry types and field names, meaning that
@InCollection{pines,
  Author       = {Pines, Shlomo},
  Editor       = {Twersky, Isadore},
  title        = {The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to {Al-Farabi}, {ibn
                  Bajja}, and {Maimonides}},
  Date         = 1979,
  Booktitle    = {Studies in Medieval {Jewish} History and Literature},
  Publisher    = {Harvard University Press},
  LOCATION     = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  PaGeS        = {82-109},
}

and
@incollection{pines,
  author       = {Pines, Shlomo},
  editor       = {Twersky, Isadore},
  title        = {The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to {Al-Farabi}, {ibn
                  Bajja}, and {Maimonides}},
  date         = 1979,
  booktitle    = {Studies in Medieval {Jewish} History and Literature},
  publisher    = {Harvard University Press},
  location     = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  pages        = {82-109},
}

are parsed as the same entry. This may suggest that InCollection and incollection are equivalent in all places, but unfortunately, they aren't.
The biblatex documentation explains (§2 Database Guide, p. 7)

All entry types and field names are given in all-lowercase form here. This is how the entry types and field names are given in the data model. While the Biber/BibTeX input side is case insensitive, the LaTeX side is case sensitive and uses the exact capitalisation from the data model. This means that the input in the .bib file may use any capitalisation of entry types and field names, but when the fields are used in the LaTeX document---for example in \citefield---the capitalisation must match the capitalisation in the data model, for standard types and fields that would be all lowercase.

So the lines you need are
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, incollection]{citetitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook, article, unpublished, incollection]{title}{#1}

note that the standard definition for title in biblatex.def are
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{#1}

so if you want to remove the quotation marks, you might want to do
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1}

See also Remove Quotation Marks from Style.

See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/90fb984847a401bf78a3f22e400482a3ac4e8014, https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/278 for the history of the quoted text in the docs.
